# inetmgr is not working in windows 7

Tags: iis, asp.net, deployment

i'm deploying an application into the remote server, while i'm opening the inetmgr from run command it is not working.Previously it used to work.Sometime it is opening but when i run the application the iis7 is terminating and again i tried run the inetmgr from run command it is not working i mean the windows is not showing(iis).I tried some solutions provided in the net but those are working for me.Please can anybody provide me any solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What "solution on the Internet" did you try? What does "not working" mean? What are you trying to do, error messages, ...?

Comment: sfc /scannow in the command prompt,http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html,http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistaapps/thread/3928aa45-497c-4f2a-93fb-faaa7946d973/, These are the solutions i have tried but no solution founded the exact error.